# ManyToMany with SQLalchemy in Fastapi

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, fastapi, pydantic

I have a following models with many-to-many relations:

```py
dashboard_customer_association = Table(
    "entry_customer",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("entry_id", ForeignKey("entry.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("customer_id", ForeignKey("customer.id"), primary_key=True),
)


class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "customer"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(64), unique=True, index=True)


class Entry(Base):
    __tablename__ = "entry"

    id = Column(String(16), primary_key=True, index=True)
    customer = relationship("Customer", secondary=dashboard_customer_association)
```

Here's my `pydantic` schema.

```py
class Entry(BaseModel):
    id: str
    customer: List[str] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

I've managed to insert the data and create the customers alongside,
but the problem is when I'm trying to retrieve data:

```py
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for Entry
response -> customer -> 0
  str type expected (type=type_error.str)
response -> customer -> 1
  str type expected (type=type_error.str)
```

I understand that the `Customer` object is not a string, so `customer`
field cannot be directly serialized as `List[str]`, but I fail to see
how am I supposed to do the conversion.

I return the data with the following function:

```py
def get_data(item_id):
    instance = db.query(models.Entry).filter(models.Entry.id == item_id).first()
    return instance
```

I was trying to set `instance.customer = [customer.name for customer in instance.customer]`,
but SQLalchemy prevents that. What is the right way to do that?

Comment: The best way would be to simply match the schema to the returned data and have a Customer object as well. You can also use a validator to return a single value if that's not an option: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/

Comment: Validators seem to work fine here, that's what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to simply match the schema to the returned data and have a Customer object as well.

However, if that is not an option, you can [use a validator to change the content](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/) when it's being populated - i.e. just return a single value from your Customer object.

```
@validator('customer')
def customer_as_string(cls, v):
    return v.name
```